# Cannot unset "selected" in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating plugin for copying html elements and I have problem with `<select>`.
After new element is appended to container I can't change `<select>` value. When I'm try to click on it always selecting first value. When I remove `"selected="selected"` via browser console manually it's starting work. But somehow I'm not able to remove it via JavaScript.
I have tried:

```
objElement.find('select').each(function(){                        
    var objThs = $(this);    
    //option 1
    objThs.val([]);
    //option 2
    objThs[0].selectedIndex = -1
    //option 3
    objThs.prop('selectedIndex', -1);
    //option 4
    objThs.find('[selected]').prop('selected', false);                       
});
```

But nothing is changed. 
Of course if I console log `objThs.find('[selected]').length` it's returning 1.

Comment: A `select` element *cannot* have no selectedIndex. By default it is the first element: `objThs[0].selectedIndex = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

*At least one* of the select options must be selected (or showing rather). Why don't you add the first `<option>` as a dummy option and default to that?

```
<select>
    <option>Please choose one</option>
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes I have this option with `value=""`, the problem occurs when I copy element which have `option="selected"` hard coded in HTML, when I change value to `""` it's showing proper (first) option but `selected="selected"` is still in another option and I can't change value of this select

Answer (score 0):

OK I found solution:

```
objThs.find('option').removeAttr('selected')
```

working fine. But still I don't know why other options have failed?